# How to add Help chapters to Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a strange problem with my `Matlab R2009b` on my `Mac Snow Leopard`.

When I click to get the Help on Matlab  : [image]

I get some chapters, not all of them  : (list en the left)

[image]

I still have the installation file, I tried to reinstall the whole thing , I first deleted Matlab app from /applications/ but nothing changed.

I really need help, I use that help frequently.

Comment: What is missing? Is the corresponding toolbox installed and licensed?

Comment: Fuzzy logic chapter and a loot of toolboxes I have installed ...

Comment: Can you post the output of `ver`?

Comment: I have stopped using the included matlab help as it slows down the whole thing. Now I use only the online one. Unless you have to work offline, I would suggest that. http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/matlab/index.html . One issue that comes up though: if you don't have the very last version of matlab, you can't know if the help always corresponds.

Comment: >> ver
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MATLAB Version 7.9.0.529 (R2009b)
MATLAB License Number: 161051
Operating System: Mac OS X  Version: 10.6.8 Build: 10K549 
Java VM Version: Java 1.6.0_65-b14-462-10M4609 with Apple Inc. Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode
------------------------------

Comment: I would like to use the help for offline .

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution , it is simple, u just have to look on parameters :

[image]